# customizing sleep button options in gsettings does nothing 17.04

Tags: suspend, power-management, gsettings

I used dconf-editor to edit the sleep button options in org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power and it does nothing, all I want to do is replace everything that makes Ubuntu sleep with turning off the monitor, and the last step in this process was changing the setting, I know the problem isn't dconf-editor because gsettings shows that the settings were changed to what I want.

My keyboard is a old cheap emachines keyboard that uses a ps/2 port if that makes any difference.

Clarification:
What I want is for button-sleep to be set to 'blank' but when I set it to 'blank' it does not blank the screen when I press sleep, instead it suspends the computer

Output of cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details.

[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
HandleSuspendKey=ignore
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
#UserTasksMax=33%
```

Comment: Can you run the command `cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf` and include the output in your question?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Done!

Comment: Change`#HandleSuspendKey=suspend` to `HandleSuspendKey=ignore`, save and reboot. If it works I"ll write a full answer explaining the process.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It didn't work.

Comment: Check the power settings within system settings.